# ¿Por qué en caso de empate el programa no finaliza?

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un sencillo juego del *3 en línea*.

Tengo un *problemilla*: cuando se consumen todos los movimientos y no hay un ganador, el programa no finaliza (como sería lo esperado), sino que continúa su ejecución.

No se como *minimizar* mas el código y hacer reproducible el problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char t1 = '1',t2 = '2',t3 = '3',t4 = '4',t5 = '5',t6 = '6',t7 = '7',t8 = '8',t9 = '9';
    char turno = 'X';
    char casilla = ' ';
    int fin = 0;
    int error = 0;
    int contador = 0;

    printf(".-----+-----+-----.\n");
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t7,t8,t9);
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf("|-----+-----+-----|\n");
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t4,t5,t6);
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf("|-----+-----+-----|\n");
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t1,t2,t3);
    printf("|     |     |     |\n");
    printf(".-----+-----+-----.\n");

    do{
        printf("Juega %c [1-9] " , turno);
        scanf("%s", &casilla);

        if(casilla=='1' || casilla=='2'|| casilla=='3'|| casilla=='4'
           || casilla=='5'|| casilla=='6'|| casilla=='7'|| casilla=='8'|| casilla=='9'){

            if(casilla == t1){
                t1 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t2){
                t2 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t3){
                t3 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t4){
                t4 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t5){
                t5= turno;
            }else if (casilla == t6){
                t6 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t7){
                t7 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t8){
                t8 = turno;
            }else if (casilla == t9){
                t9 = turno;
            }else{
                error = 1;
            }
        } else{
            error = 1;
        }

        if (error == 1){
            printf("ERROR!!!\n");
            error = 0;
        }else{
            if((t1==t2 && t2==t3)||(t4==t5 && t5==t6)||(t7==t8 && t8==t9)
                || (t1==t4 && t4==t7)||(t2==t5 && t5==t8)||(t3==t6 && t6==t9)
                ||( t1==t5 && t5==t9)||(t3==t5 && t5==t7)) {
                fin = 1;
            }else{
                if(turno == 'X'){
                    turno = 'O';
                }else{
                    turno = 'X';
                }
            }
        }
        printf(".-----+-----+-----.\n");
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t7,t8,t9);
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf("|-----+-----+-----|\n");
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t4,t5,t6);
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf("|-----+-----+-----|\n");
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf("|  %c  |  %c  |  %c  |\n",t1,t2,t3);
        printf("|     |     |     |\n");
        printf(".-----+-----+-----.\n");

        contador++;
    }
    while((fin != 1) && (contador <= 8));
    {
        if(fin==1)printf("GANADOR!!! %c\n" , turno);
            else printf("EMPATE!!! \n");
    }


}
```

Comment: Es buena práctica explicar un poco que hace tu código y además, poner comentarios en el código que ayuden al programador y a la gente que lea tu código a entender qué es lo que hace.

Comment: contador nunca se modifica por lo que la unica opcion de salir del bucle es que fin sea 1 por lo que siempre saldra GANADOR

Comment: @Lithorell tal vez lo estoy mirando mal, pero yo veo que `contador` se modifica al final del `do`-`while`.

Comment: @ROcas ¿Estás confundiendo el `do`-`while`, que es una sola estructura de control, con dos estructuras de control independientes, una `do` y una `while` (que por separado no existen en [tag:c++])?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster creo que antes no estaba. busque contador y solo habia 2 coincidencias, la declaracion y el if.

Comment: @Lithorell tenia que estar. el unico edit es el mio y no modifiqué el codigo

Comment: @Lithorell pensé lo mismo, por eso revisé las ediciones del mensaje y (salvo error u omisión) vi que `contador` se actualiza al final del `do`-`while` en todas las versiones.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pues entonces tendre que poner un bug a mozilla por el buscador de firefox XD

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Conceptualmente no puede haber un empate en un juego por turnos, siempre habrá un turno en que uno de los jugadores gane, aunque en el siguiente turno fueran a empatar.

Comment: ¿Cómo que no puede haber un empate? Puede haberlo exactamente igual que existen las tablas en ajedrez. El juego llega a un estado en el que o bien no se pueden realizar más jugadas o bien resulta imposible que un jugador consiga ganar. Realmente no entiendo porque se ha cerrado la pregunta: el problema me parece claro, de hecho yo lo estuve mirando ayer y no encontré porqué no funcionaba.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes 1 problema: Declaras

```
char casilla = ' ';
```

pero luego haces

```
scanf("%s", &casilla);
```

Es decir, internamente usas un `char`, pero lees **una cadena**. Toda cadena, como mínimo, te ocupará **2** *bytes*: para el carácter, y para el `0` final.

En cada lectura, **te sales fuera** del espacio reservado, *pisando* el valor de otras variables; ello produce comportamientos *curiosos*.

Para solucionarlo, basta con hacer

```
scanf("%c", &casilla);
```

con lo cual ya lees 1 solo *byte*. Ahora bien, esto presenta un problema extra: el ' \n' que pulsas **se queda en el *buffer* de entrada**, por lo que tenemos que eliminarlo. Una posible opción es cambiar tu formato de entrada por `" %c"`, **colocando un espacio** delante de `%c`.

Así pues, la solución final: cambia

```
scanf("%s", &casilla);
```

por

```
scanf(" %c", &casilla);
```

Con ese sencillo cambio, todo funciona como debiera.